# Multiple indented sub-equations within an align environment

Tags: align

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}

& E=MC^2 \\

\begin{flalign}

& U = \frac{1}{2} + bh & V = \frac{1}{2} - bh & B=H \\ % want to have this sub equation indented\\

& H= \frac{1}{2}(S-X) & H1= \frac{1}{2}(S+X) & B=H \\ % want to have this sub equation indented

\end{flalign}

& Y=MX +b 

\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Please I would appreciate it if I could be helped align my sub equations within an align environment with numbering of sub equations as (2.1 a) and major equations as (2.1)

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear to me, and you cannot nest an `\flalign` environment in another environment. Could you explain more, with a drawing if necessary?

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % for equation numbering section.equation
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for demo

\begin{document}    
    \blindtext
    \setcounter{section}{2} % just for demo
    \begin{align}       
         e&=mc^2  \\                
            &&U&= \frac{1}{2} + bh  &V&= \frac{1}{2} - bh  &B&=H \tag{\theequation{} a} \\          
            &&H&= \frac{1}{2}(S-X)  &H_1&= \frac{1}{2}(S+X) &B&=H \tag{\theequation{} b} \\         
         Y&=mX +b       
    \end{align}
    \blindtext  
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

or alternatively:

```
\begin{align}       
    \MoveEqLeft[3] e=mc^2  \\ % change the number [3] to other values in order to change the indent             
        U&= \frac{1}{2} + bh  &V&= \frac{1}{2} - bh  &B&=H \tag{\theequation{} a}\\     
        H&= \frac{1}{2}(S-X)  &H_1&= \frac{1}{2}(S+X) &B&=H \tag{\theequation{} b}\\                
    \MoveEqLeft[3] Y=mX +b      
\end{align}
```

[image]

---

or a third alternative:

```
\begin{alignat}{7}  
    e&=mc^2  \\                 
        & &&U&&= \frac{1}{2} + bh,  &&V&&= \frac{1}{2} - bh,  &&B&&=H \tag{\theequation{} a}\\      
        & &&H&&= \frac{1}{2}(S-X),\quad  &&H_1&&= \frac{1}{2}(S+X),\quad &&B&&=H \tag{\theequation{} b}\\               
     Y&=mX +b       
\end{alignat}
```

[image]

---

And finally:

If you want to change the indent in the last example, just change the kerning in the first row:

```
\begin{alignat}{7}  
    e&=mc^2\mkern-20mu  \\ % change this value to nevative or positive values in order to change the indent             
        & &&U&&= \frac{1}{2} + bh,  &&V&&= \frac{1}{2} - bh,  &&B&&=H \tag{\theequation{} a}\\      
        & &&H&&= \frac{1}{2}(S-X),\quad  &&H_1&&= \frac{1}{2}(S+X),\quad &&B&&=H \tag{\theequation{} b}\\               
     Y&=mX +b\mkern-10000mu % leave this value      
\end{alignat}
```

Comment: @user28251 You are very welcome. If you think, this is your answer, you could accept it by clicking on the left side check mark. Like this, the issue gets closed. Thanks.

Comment: Sure you got it